# The $n$’th Harmonic number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The $n$’th Harmonic number is defined as follows: $$H_n = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 +\ldots + \frac1n$$ for $n\geq 1$.

a) Show that for all $n≥0$: $H_{2^n} \geq 1+\frac n2$.

b) Show that for all $n≥0$: $H_{2^n} \leq 1+n$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054537/harmonic-number-inequality) question.

Comment: I don't think you have the question right.  It looks like Hn=n, so a is easy and b is false.  A tutorial for writing math on this site is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  As this is your fourth question, you could learn to format things.

Comment: @Tiina I edited the question with proper math-formatting and made some assumptions about what I thought you meant so please take a look and see if it is correct (click 'Edit' and 'Rollback' to cancel the edit if it is wrong).

Comment: @Winther:  That was a huge guess about what OP wanted.  Certainly the $H_n$ part is right and I suspect the rest.  I would suggest making OP fix things when they are this bad.

Comment: Homework problem? What have you tried?

Comment: it is not a homework question, it is a sample question for my midterm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) Assume it is true for $k.$ We want to prove that it's true for $k+1.$ First note that, $H_{2^{k+1}} = H_{2^k} +\frac{1}{2^k+1} +….+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}.$ Now, for each $k \in \mathbb N, 2^k < 2^k+1, 2^k<2^k+2, \cdots, 2^k<2^{k+1}.$ So $\frac{1}{2^k+1} +….+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq 1.$

Comment: The last sentence has a correct formula, but it's not clear exactly how you derived it from $2^k < 2^{k+1}.$ I think I would replace $2^k < 2^{k+1}$ with a couple of other steps.

Comment: @DavidK: There was a typo and some part was missing. I didn't realize. Sorry for that. Now fixed. Please take a look and see if there is any mistake.

Comment: OK, it is clear to me now what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

(a). Base case:
for $n = 0,$ we have $H_{2^n}= H_1 = 1,$ and $1 + 0/2 = 1.$

Induction Step:
Let's assume $k \geq 0$ is an arbitrary number, and it holds for $k$:
$H_{2^k} \geq 1+ k/2.$
Then we prove it for $k+1$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
H_{2^{k+1}} & = & H_{2^k} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^k+1} + \ldots +
                                              \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}_{\text{($2^k$ terms)}} \\
         & \geq &1 + k/2 + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^k+1} + \ldots +
                                              \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}_{\text{($2^k$ terms)}} \\
         & \geq & 1 + k/2 + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} + \ldots +
                                              \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}_{\text{($2^k$ terms)}} \\
         & = & 1 + k/2 + \frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}} \\
         & = & 1 + k/2 +1/2 \\
         & = & 1+ (k+1)/2
\end{eqnarray}$$
so, it holds for $k+1.$ Therefore, by induction we proved it is true for all $n \geq 0.$

Comment: I am not sure about part b

Comment: Dear @Tiina, I've edited your answer, see if it's fine. For future reference here is a link for MathJax: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For part b use (make a sketch to see why): $H_n \leq 1 + \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} = 1 + \log n$.

Comment: @Winther: There is an alternate way to do it. Please see my solution below.

Comment: @Tina I restored parts of your formulas that were deleted in a previous edit, and reworded the start of your induction step: in particular, at the beginning of an inductive step one says something like "it holds for $k$" without specifying which $k$. Also, your ">" inequality was not true when $k=0$ (because $2^0 + 1 = 2^{0+1} = 2$), so I changed it to $\geq$, which makes the inequality true for all $k\geq 0$. Sorry for doing rather than suggesting, but the changes were complicated to describe; you can put back any parts you don't like.